# "the only thing you did today was breathe" vs. "the only thing you did today was TO breathe"

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

> Sometimes it's okay if the only thing you did today was **breathe**.

In this sentence, should I use a bare infinitive, 'breathe', or 'to breathe'? I think I should use a bare infinitive, otherwise structure of the sentence is not correct.

Comment: A bare infinitive i.e. breathe is what everybody would generally use. The structure of both of them is grammatically acceptable, but 'breathe' is more common in everyday usage. Most of us prefer to cut down on the number of words we're using in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It´s correct to say that

> “the only thing you did today was breathe”

You do not need to use to infinitive.